# Orderings and Linear orderings

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, combinatorial-proofs

How can you prove that any two n-element sets are isomorphic? I've been stuck on this problem for a while and could really use an explanation because I am not getting it.

I still don't even understand isomorphism even after looking at the definition for a couple days.

Comment: How does the title relate to the post? Are you trying to prove that any two _linear orderings_ on $n$-element sets are isomorphic? Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4532316/edit) to clarify. Also, it is essential you understand the definition of "isomorphic," so I suggest editing to describe the definition you were given, and what about it you do not understand.

Comment: As @MikeEarnest notes, based on the title it sounds like you want to prove that any two linearly ordered $n$-element sets are order-isomorphic.  Start by sending the least element of the first set to the least element of the second set.  Then proceed inductively, at each stage sending the least unused element of the first set to the least unused element of the second set.  You'll need to prove (a) this step is always possible until you've defined the complete map, (b) the process terminates, and (c) the resulting map is an order-isomorphism.